# UDP stream reading like socat

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

I'm developing a tool which is analyzing video stream.
I've worked with a file, I generate the file with this socat command (that someone's given to me):

```
socat -u UDP4-RECV:1234,ip-add-membership=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0.0.0.0 CREATE:temp.ts
```

But now I'd like to work directly with the UDP stream.
With this code, I've tried to read the first received block and write it on the console, but I don#t get anything - the program gets stuck...

```
void Decoder::open_udp_stream(std::string ip_adress)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    udp::endpoint receiver_endpoint (boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), 1234);

    udp::socket socket(io_service);
    socket.open(udp::v4());

    boost::array<char, 128> recv_buf;
    udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
    size_t len = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf), sender_endpoint);

    std::cout.write(recv_buf.data(), len);
}
```

What should I do to get the blocks from this IP, as with the socat command ?

Comment: Is this a multicast stream you're trying to receive? If so, why do you have no multicast code?

Comment: Thanks a lot David, that was the problem. I'm very new to network and network programming... I've tried the boost example for multicast receiver, and I get the stream data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working (thanks David Schwarz)

```
void Decoder::open_udp_stream(std::string ip_adress)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
    // Create the socket so that multiple may be bound to the same address.
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(
                                                   boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("0.0.0.0"), 1234);
    socket_.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
    socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
    socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);

    // Join the multicast group.
    socket_.set_option(
                       boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")));

    boost::array<char, BUF_SIZE> recv_buf;
    size_t len = socket_.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf), sender_endpoint);

    std::cout.write(recv_buf.data(), len);
}
```